# How can I update serialized data in a Rails/MariaDB backend?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization, mariadb

Currently, I have some `QueuedImages` that become `GalleryImages` once certain conditions are met.

```
@image = GalleryImage.new(image_params.except(:tags))
@image.user = current_user

@queued = QueuedImage.new(user: current_user)
@queued.image = @image
```

Before saving this method, transform the images into JSON:

```
  def image_to_json    
    self.image_data = @image.to_json(include: :plain_images)
  end
```

I'm trying to update the serialized hash/JSON like this:

```
def update
    @queued = QueuedImage.find(params[:id])
    hash_as_string = @queued.image_data
    i_data = JSON.parse(hash_as_string.gsub('=>', ':'))
    i_data["title"] = params["title"]
    i_data["description"] = params["description"]
    i_data["folder_id"] = params["folder_id"]
    i_data["nsfw"] = params["nsfw"]
    i_data["tags"] = params["tags"]
    @queued.image_data = i_data

    if @queued.save
      render json: @queued, scope: current_user
    else
      render json: @queued.errors.as_json(full_messages: true), scope: current_user, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
```

Which throws me a parse error, what am I doing wrong?

How can I properly update the serialized string?

The thing is that when it transforms from a `QueuedImage` to a `GalleryImage`, another method takes that data and evaluates it and creates the new `GalleryImage`, so it has to be in the exact format, and I believe what I'm doing in the update method is wrong, even though I save it as a string in the DB.